# How can I browse a specific level on a XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

This is the XML that I have :

```
<ordinanze>
    <dataagg>17/10/2012 ore 16:30</dataagg>
    <ordinanza>
        <numero>02/2012</numero>
        <titolo>02/2012</titolo>
    </ordinanza>

    <ordinanza>
        <numero>02/2012</numero>
        <titolo>02/2012</titolo>
    </ordinanza>

    <ordinanza>
        <numero>02/2012</numero>
        <titolo>02/2012</titolo>
    </ordinanza>
</ordinanze>
```

and I'd like to browse the first level with the attribute `ordinanza` (not the rest) So, 3 nodes in the foreach. How can I do it?

My code :

```
XmlNodeList StudentNodeList = myXmlDocument.SelectNodes("ordinanza");

foreach (XmlNode node in StudentNodeList)
{
    Response.Write(node.SelectSingleNode("//numero[1]").InnerText);
}
```

but it prints nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using Linq To Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //or XDocument.Load(fileName)
var list =  xDoc.Descendants("ordinanza")
                .Select(n => new
                {
                    Numero = n.Element("numero").Value,
                    Titolo = n.Element("titolo").Value,
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: it doesnt found linq to xml, also with `using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: @markzzz And you are sure you use `XDocument` not `XmlDocument` ?

Comment: You rock as well :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try using XElement and [Linq to XML](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564).

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is incorrect. Here is my favorite [XPath Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C).
To answer your question of how to get three nodes in the foreach try

```
var students = myXmlDocument.SelectNodes("/ordinanze/ordinanza");
```

However, I do suggest you dabble with some LINQ if you're not familiar with it yet.